# Displaying related results with group concat

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all events for the person corresponding to feed X AND return the other people attending that event... in a single query.

```
 events (TABLE)
 - id int (10)
 - name varchar (20)

 events_people (TABLE)
 - id int (10)
 - event_id int (10)
 - person_id int (10)

 feed (TABLE)
 - id int (10)
 - feed_id varchar (20)
 - person_id int (10)

 people (TABLE)
 - id int (10)
 - first_name varchar (20)
```

I can get this far with this simple query:

```
SELECT events.id AS event_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(people.first_name)) AS attending
FROM events
LEFT JOIN events_people ON events.id = events_people.event_id
LEFT JOIN people ON events_people.person_id = people.id
LEFT JOIN feed ON events_people.person_id = feed.person_id
GROUP BY events.id
```

but as soon as I add a conditional like `WHERE feed.feed_id IN ('SHFDskdf')`, it filters all users who are not related to feed X and therefore breaks the group concatenation.

I'm sure this isn't rocket science, but after spending a couple of hours on this I sure feel like it is.

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3143c/2/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT events.id AS event_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(people.first_name)) AS attending
FROM events LEFT JOIN
     events_people
     ON events.id = events_people.event_id LEFT JOIN
     people
     ON events_people.person_id = people.id LEFT JOIN
     feed
     ON events_people.person_id = feed.person_id AND feed.feed_id IN ('SHFDskdf')
GROUP BY events.id;
```

EDIT:

The issue is that the filter has no impact on `people.first_name`.  You can fix this with a `case` statement:

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT case when f.person_id is not null then p.first_name end) AS attending
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     events_people ep
     ON e.id = ep.event_id LEFT JOIN
     people p
     ON ep.person_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     feed f
     ON ep.person_id = f.person_id AND f.feed_id IN ('SHFDskdf')
GROUP BY e.id;
```

This should do what you want.

EDIT II:

Now I think I know what you want:

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.first_name) AS attending
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     events_people ep
     ON e.id = ep.event_id LEFT JOIN
     people p
     ON ep.person_id = p.id LEFT JOIN
     feed f
     ON ep.person_id = f.person_id 
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING SUM(f.feed_id IN ('SHFDskdf')) > 0;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for the answer. Its close, but its not working correctly. All events are being displayed, even if the user (or feed) has nothing to do with them: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3143c/8/0

For event 3, user tim is not part of the event but the event is still being returned.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Unfortunately thats still not quite there, now only the feed user is being returned. Perhaps I have approached this in completely the wrong way...? To recap, I am trying to get all event id's that user X is going to, AND for those events also return the list of other users... Perhaps it is not possible in a single query, but it looked like we were so close... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3143c/13

Comment: @Tim . . . Oh, you want a `having` clause.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I needed. Thank-you so much for your time and efforts :)